# Setting proxy for JBoss (ESB) debugging with Fiddler

Tags: jboss, proxy, fiddler, esb

Running a JBoss 5.1.0GA with a JBoss ESB 4.10 installed on a Win 7 Professional.
I would like to route (SOAP)requests from ESB (org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.soap.SOAPClient) through a proxy (Fiddler).

I have tried the following settings, but I dont see any requests in Fiddler:

In run.conf.bat:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
 -Dhtttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true
```

In properties-service.xml:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
name="jboss:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">

<attribute name="Properties">
  http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
  http.proxyPort=8888
  htttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
  https.proxyPort=8888
  proxySet=true
</attribute>

</mbean>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same problem...

Comment: @walts As I recall it - I dropped Fiddler and used Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Dhttp.proxyHost=localhost -Dhtttps.proxyHost=localhost` instead.